# Printing Specific Rows in R

Tags: r

Hi guys so I am working with a large data frame that records employee time card data for specific months.  I want to print out the entire row of employees who record a MAXIMUM of three zeros in three different months.  I believe I need to use the apply function: apply(Employee, 1, ...) where Employee is the name of the data frame, 1 allows it to iterate over each row, but I am unsure how to select for only those that have three or fewer zeros in its row.  I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3):

You could use `rowSums()`.  Here's an example with some fake data.

```
> d <- data.frame(X1 = c(0, 1, 0, 0), X2 = c(0, 2, 2, 0), 
                  X3 = c(0, 2, 0, 0), X4 = c(3, 0, 0, 0))
> d
#   X1 X2 X3 X4
# 1  0  0  0  3
# 2  1  2  2  0
# 3  0  2  0  0
# 4  0  0  0  0
```

The we can subset for those rows where the logical value of `x == 0` sums to 3 or less:

```
> d[rowSums(d == 0, na.rm = TRUE) <= 3, ]
#   X1 X2 X3 X4
# 1  0  0  0  3
# 2  1  2  2  0
# 3  0  2  0  0
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something just using `which` and `rowSums` instead of `apply`?

```
Employee[which(rowSums(Employee==0)<=3),]
```

Comment: Your `which()` is unnecessary.